# Computing the Same Results MATLAB ODE45 and Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, ode, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to understand how to get the same results in Python as I get in MATLAB. Attached is the source code of what I have tried, results being incorrect for the two different methods. At the bottom of the code is the expected solution as the result of MATLAB. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```python
from scipy.integrate import ode
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np


def function2(x, mu):
    x, y, z = x
    r1 = np.sqrt((x + mu) ** 2 + (y ** 2) + (z ** 2))
    r2 = np.sqrt((x - (1 - mu)) ** 2 + (y ** 2) + (z ** 2))
    u1_x = 1 - (1 - mu) * (1 / (r1 ** 3) - 3 * ((x + mu) ** 2) / (r1 ** 5)) - \
           mu * (1 / (r2 ** 3) - 3 * ((x - (1 - mu)) ** 2) / (r2 ** 5))
    u2_y = 1 - (1 - mu) * (1 / (r1 ** 3)) - 3 * y ** 2 / (r1 ** 5) - \
           mu * (1 / r2 ** 3 - 3 * y ** 2 / r2 ** 5)
    u3_z = (-1) * (1 - mu) * (1 / r1 ** 3) - 3 * z ** 2 / r1 ** 5 - mu * \
           (1 / r2 ** 3 - 3 * z ** 2 / r2 ** 5)
    u1_y = 3 * (1 - mu) * y * (x + mu) / r1 ** 5 + \
           3 * mu * y * (z - (1 - mu)) / r2 ** 5
    u1_z = 3 * (1 - mu) * z * (x + mu) / r1 ** 5 + \
           3 * mu * z * (x - (1 - mu)) / r2 ** 5
    u2_z = 3 * (1 - mu) * y * z / r1 ** 5 + 3 * mu * y * z / r2 ** 5
    u3_y = u2_z
    u2_x = u1_y
    u3_x = u1_z
    gmatrix = np.array([[u1_x, u1_y, u1_z],
                        [u2_x, u2_y, u2_z],
                        [u3_x, u3_y, u3_z]])
    return gmatrix


def function(t, y, mu):
    x = y[36:39]
    GMatrix = function2(x, mu)
    OxO = np.zeros([3, 3])
    Ind = np.identity(3)
    K = np.array([[0, 2, 0], [-2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
    Df = np.bmat([[OxO[0], Ind[0]],
                  [OxO[1], Ind[1]],
                  [OxO[2], Ind[2]],
                  [GMatrix[0], K[0]],
                  [GMatrix[1], K[1]],
                  [GMatrix[2], K[2]]])
    Df = np.reshape(Df, (6, 6))
    A_temp = np.squeeze(np.array(y))
    A_temp = A_temp.flatten()
    B_temp = [0]*42
    for i in range(len(A_temp)):
       B_temp[i] = A_temp[i]
    B_temp = B_temp[:-6]
    B_temp = np.array(B_temp)
    A = B_temp.reshape(6, 6)
    DfA = np.matmul(Df, A)
    a = [0] * 36
    b = np.squeeze(np.array(DfA))
    b = b.flatten()
    for i in range(len(b)):
        a[i] = b[i]
    r1 = np.sqrt((mu+y[36])**2 + (y[37]**2) + (y[38]**2))
    r2 = np.sqrt((1-mu-y[36])**2 + (y[37]**2) + (y[38]**2))
    m1 = 1 - mu
    m2 = mu
    c = [y[39],
         y[40],
         y[41],
         y[36] + 2 * y[40] + m1 * (-mu - y[36]) / (r1**3) + m2 * (1-mu-y[36]) / (r2**3),
         y[37] - 2 * y[39] - m1 * (y[37]) / (r1**3) - m2 * y[37] / (r2**3),
         -m1 * y[38] / (r1**3) - m2 * y[38] / (r2**3)]
    ydot = a + c
    return ydot
```

## The `driver` that will integrate the ODE(s):

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = 0
    tf = 1.450000000000000
    mu = 3.054248395728148e-06
    x_n = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0,
           0.9919755553772727, 0.0, -0.0018716577540106951,
           0.0, -0.0117506137115032, 0.0]
    #meth = 'adams'
    meth = 'bdf'
    r = ode(function).set_integrator('vode',method=meth,rtol=1e-13,
                                                        atol=1e-22,                                                      
                                      with_jacobian=False)
    r.set_initial_value(x_n,t0).set_f_params(mu)
    r.integrate(tf)
    temp = r.y
    index2 = [41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36]
    temp = np.delete(temp,index2)
    temp = temp.reshape(6,6)
    time = [t0, tf]
    states = integrate.solve_ivp(fun=lambda t, y:
                                 function(t, x_n, mu),
                                 t_span=time, y0=x_n, method='LSODA', dense_output=True,
                                 rtol=1e-13,atol=1e-22)
    new_time = states.t
    new_temp = states.y[:,-1]
    index2 = [41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36]
    new_temp = np.delete(new_temp,index2)
    new_temp = new_temp.reshape(6,6)
    print(new_temp)
    print(temp)
```

desired solution // MATLAB ode45 & ode113 same result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtWqa.png)

This is part of a greater series of scripts that I am writing and would prefer not have my code in MATLAB. I know the MATLAB answer is correct because the the end solutions provides the desired orbit I am trying to create. I should also note that it would appear that MATLAB is using adaptive step sizes and not a predefined time series one would create like in Python `np.linspace(start,end,step)`

A suggested method was the ivp_solver rk45 with dense_out = true
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWsjE.png)

however this method also does not provide the correct results.
here are the results to that method:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXTIj.png)

Update: When I manually calculate RK45 on paper with the first time step used by MATLAB I get the same answer. Also, when I force the time series to use the first time interval I get the same answer with the solve_ivp->RK45 with dense out. However even when using the same full time series from MATLAB I get results different from MATLAB.

@Lutz Lehmann After doing some research and testing of a variety of different methods you are correct in that r.integrate only integrate once. In order to integrate at each point a loop is required. Additionally, I was able to get ode and solve_ivp to same answer (although it is the wrong answer). When using solve_ivp I had to do the following which gave me the same answer when using ode.

```python
    r = integrate.solve_ivp(fun=lambda t, y: function(t, y, mu),
                          t_span=time, y0=y, method='RK45', dense_output=True,
                            rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22)
    i = 0
    while r.t[i] < tf:
        r = integrate.solve_ivp(fun=lambda t, y:  function(t, y, mu),
                                t_span=time, y0=y, method='RK45', dense_output=True,
                                rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22)
        print(r.t[i])
        i += 1
    new_time = r.t
    new_temp = r.y[:, -1]
    index2 = [41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36]
    new_temp = np.delete(new_temp, index2)
    print(new_temp)

    r = ode(function)
    r.set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', rtol=1e-13, atol=1e-22, with_jacobian=False)
    r.set_initial_value(y, t0)
    r.set_f_params(mu)
    r.integrate(tf)

    t = []
    Y = [y]

    while r.t < tf:
        r.integrate(tf, step=True)
        Y = np.vstack((Y, [r.y]))
        t.append([r.t])

    new_temp = Y[-1, :]
    index2 = [41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36]
    new_temp = np.delete(new_temp, index2)
    test = new_temp.reshape(6,6)
    print(test)
```

I should note that the method using solve_ivp is much slower compared to using ode. The difference in speed yielding the same result probably means that ode is the preferred method (not sure).

This was the solution I got.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmYsk.png)

Unfortunately what means is that based on this latest update conducted from your last post I am back to where I started. ODE and solve_ivp provide the same answer however this is still not the solution.

Comment: You can debug your ODE functions easily---pass the same inputs and see if they produce the same outputs from Matlab to Python. If that's working, then check the Ode solvers---check you are using the same methods, you have the syntax correct. It's hard to answer your question though because your post isn't formatted very well (you have inconsistent formatting, lots of blank space, it's hard to read).

Comment: Python also uses adaptive time stepping. Just as you could force evaluation at prescribed times in Matlab. The main difference in quick-use situations is that `solve_ivp->RK45` does not have a `Refine` option as in `ode45` (with default value 4, interpolation of additional points). So one would have to use the dense output to fill the gaps to plot a sensible graph.

Comment: @David when debugging the functions the initial time step does produce the same result, however it is the ode solver that is wrong. I am not sure how to correct the solve to produce the same results.Sorry about the formatting it would seem as I copied and past the code form spider a lot of spaces were introduced. If you remove the spaces and correct the formatting it does run in any given python ide.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I did try the solve_ivp -> rk45 with dense output unfortunately it produced results with even greater error compared to the method presented and matlab ode45. I am concerned that the adaptive step sizing is not the same and due to the stiffness of the ode that it is producing the incorrect results. If you would like I can post the outcome of the use of solve_ivp with rk45 with dense_output = True.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I was unable to post the method you suggested in the comments so I added it to the original post. Both the method and the output can be seen now at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes when comparing the method in both MATLAB and Python the initial step results match. r1 and r2 present distance as it is dynamically changing in the system so the calculation should be (mu+x[0])**2 for r1. Depending on the system one would setup for the dynamical model you could choose switch all the positives and negatives for the same result. However if both r1 and r2 are negative this is incorrect as that would no longer represent the separation a third body from the other two. This calculation is part of the circular restricted three body problem to optimize orbits.

Comment: @LutzLehmann however I am trying to focus specifically on way the ode solver when step up the same way provides different results. Unfortunately in this case something is wrong with the Python setup or how the ode solver is attempting to get the solution.

Comment: So I did double checked the equations and double checked the cross comparison of the initial results and they do match MATLAB. At this point I am confident my mistake in how I am setting up the ode solver or how the ode solver is computing the answer. I am still not sure how to setup the ode correctly to get the same result.

Comment: You got lots of small errors in indices and parentheses in the computation of the Hessean in `function2`. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: You made some strange assumptions and thus coded unnecessary computations in the last section. `solve_ivp` is the "all-comforts" wrapper containing the complete time loop. You do not need to put it into an external time loop. The `ode` class and the newer stepper classes like `RK45` or `LSODA` proceed one internal step at a time, thus the need to wrap them in a time loop, but also the higher flexibility to encode event-action mechanisms. `solve_ivp` only has a very basic event mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the `solve_ivp` call you defined the function wrong, the correct way is

```python
fun=lambda t, y:  function(t, y, mu)
```

- The `ode` solver in the function `r.integrate` seems to perform at most one internal step. To reach the final time `tf`, you have to loop this call:

```
while r.t < tf: r.integrate(tf)
```

The results of both then are sufficiently coincident, in the leading 10 or so digits. For the source to the differences to the Matlab results see the last section.

---

PS: You can drastically reduce the second function, all the flattening and copying is not really necessary. I rewrote it as

```python
def function(t, u, mu):
    A = np.reshape(u[:36],[6,6])
    x = u[36:39]
    v = u[39:]

    GMatrix = function2(x, mu)
    OxO = np.zeros([3, 3])
    Ind = np.identity(3)
    K = np.array([[0, 2, 0], [-2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
 
    Df = np.block([[OxO, Ind],
                   [GMatrix, K]])
    DfA = np.matmul(Df, A)

    x,y,z = x
    vx,vy,vz = v
    r1 = np.sqrt((mu+x)**2 + (y**2) + (z**2))
    r2 = np.sqrt((1-mu-x)**2 + (y**2) + (z**2))
    m1 = 1 - mu
    m2 = mu

    a = [x + 2 * vy - m1 * (mu + x) / (r1**3) + m2 * (1-mu-x) / (r2**3),
         y - 2 * vx - m1 * y / (r1**3) - m2 * y / (r2**3),
         -m1 * z / (r1**3) - m2 * z / (r2**3)]

    ydot = np.concatenate([DfA.flatten(), v, a])
    return ydot
```

---

In the computation of the Hessean of the potential in `function2` there were many small errors in indices and parentheses placement. Re-organized and with more structuring variables the function can look like

```python
def function2(x, mu):
    ce1, ce2 = -mu, 1-mu
    m1, m2   = 1-mu, mu
    r1 = ((x[0]-ce1)**2+x[1]**2+x[2]**2)**0.5
    r2 = ((x[0]-ce2)**2+x[1]**2+x[2]**2)**0.5
 
    u1_x = 1 - m1 * (1 / r1**3 - 3 * (x[0] - ce1)**2 / r1**5) \
             - m2 * (1 / r2**3 - 3 * (x[0] - ce2)**2 / r2**5)

    u1_y = 3 * m1 * x[1] * (x[0] - ce1) / r1**5 \
         + 3 * m2 * x[1] * (x[0] - ce2) / r2**5

    u1_z = 3 * m1 * x[2] * (x[0] - ce1) / r1**5 \
         + 3 * m2 * x[2] * (x[0] - ce2) / r2**5

    u2_x = u1_y
    
    u2_y = 1 - m1 * (1 / r1**3 - 3 * x[1]**2 / r1**5) \
             - m2 * (1 / r2**3 - 3 * x[1]**2 / r2**5)

    u2_z = 3 * m1 * x[1] * x[2] / r1**5 + 3 * m2 * x[1] * x[2] / r2**5

    u3_x = u1_z
    u3_y = u2_z

    u3_z = - m1 * (1 / r1**3 - 3 * x[2]**2 / r1**5) \
           - m2 * (1 / r2**3 - 3 * x[2]**2 / r2**5)

    GMatrix = np.array([[u1_x, u1_y, u1_z],
                        [u2_x, u2_y, u2_z],
                        [u3_x, u3_y, u3_z]])

    return GMatrix
```

This gives the results

```
[ 23.55077315 -0.39182483  3.67078856  4.77188265  4.55322364  0.54862501]
[ -8.519012   -0.71609406 -1.5344374  -2.12546806 -1.4395364  -0.23934585]
[ -0.37941138  0.11874396 -1.39417439 -0.10224713 -0.13959515  0.19607223]
[ 43.56974185 -1.72339855  6.85563491  8.62759039  8.39374083  0.9221739 ]
[-28.39640391 -0.10433561 -4.47605353 -5.56490582 -6.06643015 -0.69034888]
```

which as far as I can see coincide with the Matlab results.

Comment: The functions have been repeatedly checked leading into the ode and the results for the first iteration match so I am confident the functions are not wrong. Now that being said they may not be the most Pythonic. I am able to test to see that your version of function also produces the same results, so thank you for the cleaner version. I also tested your fun input vs mine and it made no difference so there is no evidence to support what I have is incorrect with your corrected version, with the only visible difference being changing x_n to y in the attached solve_ivp. I am currently working

Comment: on the comment of 
    The ode solver in the function r.integrate seems to perform at most one internal step. To reach the final time tf, you have to loop this call:

while r.t < tf: r.integrate(tf)
which is syntactically incorrect however I believe you have a point that needs to be tested out so I am working correcting the syntax to see the results you have mentioned. Though this may not be the final solution the question is asking for your point may bring me one step closer. I will need to test this out and once I have results I will share them. Regardless of the complete or incomplete

Comment: solution I do want to thank you for what you have provide and hope that it does lead to the correct answer. Further testing is needed and once I have a the final solution I will post it.

Comment: I added more to the post based on your comments in the answer block. Unfortunately, this brings me no closer to the solution. However I will say that you brought up some good points and helped with my understanding of the integrate method.

Comment: Wow you did it you are 100% correct. I can't thank you enough for this and I believe if I ever actually meet you I owe you a beer.

Comment: I want your answer to be marked with a green check but for some reason the system will not let me.